# how to record a video in opencv without compression

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to record a video with opencv the frame is 1920*180 with 25 frame/s, my Problem is that when I chose to write the frame unconpressed I don't get a video I get only one picture in avi format!! here my code :

```
 using namespace cv;

 int main (){
int key = 0;
Mat frame;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cap>>frame;
    cv::VideoWriter record("video.avi",-1, 25, frame.size(), true);
        while(key!=27){
    cap>>frame;
    //cv::VideoWriter record("video.avi",-1, 25, frame.size(), true);

    record<<frame;
    imshow("",frame);
    key=waitKey(1);
}
frame.release();
cv::destroyAllWindows();

return 0 ;
  }
```

I'm use DeckLink SDI card to get the video, and when record the video with Media Express it works ? any Idea

Comment: You are fully aware of the bandwidth requirements of doing so, are you? <width>*<depth>*<color depth in bytes>*<fps>*<overhead constant> means that if you do it in 24 bit color depth, without considering overhead constant, this would require 148MB/s transfer speed. Dumb question, but does your environment meet this requirement? Or maybe I shold have asked: through Media Express, do you record successfully in uncompressed format?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with "my environment", my question is if  got a  program that can grabb a video in this dimensions, how can I do the same only with opencv, and By the way  I tryied the the Blackmagic codec and it didn't work

Comment: Seems I need to rephrase it to be simpler: did you succeed in recording _uncompressed_ video of that format by any means on your computer?

Comment: Yes I did with Media Express it's BlackMagic software I got for 10s recording 1.3GB, and that exactly what I want to do with opencv. I hope that I answered your question

Comment: I think you should add this bit of information to the question, not to have anybody else ask it. I was suspecting some kind of problem independent from the code in the background, but it is clearly not the case...

Comment: I did it writen after the code but thanks